# Converting 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates in Libgdx

Tags: math, 3d, libgdx, coordinates

I'm trying to mark a model that is moving in 3D on my 2D screen, I have position of both objects in 3D and they only move along the x and z axis so Y isn't an issue here.

Since I can't explain this that well I drew 3 pictures.
The one in the top right is the information I have, the middle left is an example of what they would look like looking down on the x z axis and the bottom one is what I'm trying to accomplish, putting some indicator around the position of the players.
[image: Example]

If anyone knows the formulas for doing this or links to an example, that'd be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is a lot easier than you'd think. All you have to do is `Camera.project(Vector3)` and that returns a vector3 you can get the x and y from.